# remove node excluding those which has specific attribute using LINQ to XML

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq-to-xml

I have xml file like this:

```
<group>
  <First_group>
  </First_group>
  <Second_group>
    <Name number="1">
    </Name>
    <Name number="2">
    </Name>
    <Name number="3">
    </Name>
  </Second_group>
  <Third_group>
  </Third_group>
</group>
```

I would like to remove nodes Name excluding one which has attribute = 1

Here is the code:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\temp\node.xml")
doc.Root.Element("Second_group").Elements("Name").Attributes("number").Value > 1.Remove()
```

But it doesn`t work.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the nodes in the underlying file, or just in the XDocument object?

Comment: Does it give you an error?  I'm not sure that LINQ will execute.

Comment: I am getting this error Error: 'Value' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute)'.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4):

It won't even compile (based on your posted code).  You're going in the right direction, but your query is a bit off.

```
Attributes("number").Value
```

Won't compile because `Value` is not a member of `Attributes` - `Attributes` returns a **collection** of attributes that match the name, and you can't compare a collection to a single value (at least not very easily).

What you really need is a `Where` clause, passing in the expression for the `Where` clause to evaluate as a predicate.  Like this:

```
Doc.Root.Element("Second_group").
Elements("Name").
Where(Function(x) CInt(x.Attribute("number").
Value) > 1).
Remove()
```

**NOTE** The above code is broken across several lines so people can see the whole query without having to scroll horizontally.  For VB.Net it should be on one single line, like this:

```
Doc.Root.Element("Second_group").Elements("Name").Where(Function(x) CInt(x.Attribute("number").Value) > 1).Remove()
```

In the above example, the Where clause takes a predicate that checks the number attribute for all the selected name elements.  `Value` returns a string, so I used `CInt` to convert it to a number.  Any "Name" elements from the "Second_group" that have an attribute "number" greater than 1 are then removed.

So your XML, after the above statement, will look like this:

```
<group>
  <First_group>
  </First_group>
  <Second_group>
    <Name number="1">
    </Name>
  </Second_group>
  <Third_group>
  </Third_group>
</group>
```

The above code was tested in a console app in VS 2012.

Comment: Hmmm... I am getting error "Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement." Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: Try putting the query all on one line (I broke it apart so people could read it without having to scroll horizontaally).  Like this:  `Doc.Root.Element("Second_group").Elements("Name").Where(Function(x) CInt(x.Attribute("number").Value) > 1).Remove()`

Comment: @Chelovek - I added the whole line combined to my answer.  Also I noticed that I had a typo in the code (Attributes instead of Attribute), which is now fixed as well.

Comment: +1. VB.NET supports multiline statements with implicit continuation since 2010. You don't need the underscore and `.` is a valid continuation character. So the line should **end** with a `.`, then it expects it to continue on the next line.

Comment: @Neolisk tested to leave only . at the end, it works too, thank you :)